# how to make big menu in drupal 7

Tags: routes, navigation

How to make the menu like this in drupal 7. There are many customer module in drupal.org, but I don't know much about which module will suit with this. I would to drop down product category when user puts cursor on product menu item.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using any of below modules :

1. [Megamenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/megamenu)

> Mega menus are a type of drop-down, which seeks to overcome some of
>   the usability drawbacks to traditional style drop-downs.

2. [Bigmenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/bigmenu)

> THIS MODULE attempts to replace the all-in-one global tree view with a
>   similar interface, but sub-trees are "collapsed" below a certain
>   level, and can be expanded as needed.

3. [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu)

> TB Mega Menu allows you to create a mega menu with an innovative
>   back-end user interface and synchronized with Drupal core menu.

4. [OM Maximenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/om_maximenu)

> That is now possible by using OM Maximenu which can create menus with
>   all other module blocks you want as attachments, modules like views,
>   slideshow, menu, user, nice menus, quicktabs, and custom blocks with
>   tables, lists, images, videos, etc.

5. [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish)

> Superfish integrates jQuery Superfish plugin with your Drupal menus.

6. [Menu Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views)

> Allows menu items to render views instead of links. This is useful for
>   creating "mega-menus".

7. [MuchoMenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/1077858)

> This module allows users to create mega menus that have mini panels as
>   their flyout content. The benefit is that ANY type of content or UI
>   can be added to the menu flyouts.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Maximenu](https://www.drupal.org/project/maximenu) . This allows you to build complex menus and also allows you to use blocks as menu items.

However you might need to some research if the menu is expected to be fully responsive.